# Solving a linear optimization problem with products and work benches

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am taking a linear algebra course and I have a homework assignment of:

```
A factory produces 5 products T1, T2, T3, T4, T5.
Products are made on 3 different work benches P1, P2, P3,
which can be used for 100, 80 and 80 hours respectively.
Products timeframes on each bench are:

----------------------------------
|benches| T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 |
|  P1   | 1  | 2  | 1  | 0  | 1  |
|  P2   | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |
|  P3   | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |

How many products should the factory make to earn the most profit,
 if we know the profit margin is as follows:
T1 profit is 2 units
T2 profit is 1 units
T3 profit is 3 units
T4 profit is -1 units (Earns loss)
T5 profit is 2 units
```

So far I tried solving it with simple linear equations (like f(x) = 2x+0,5y+3z+0a,+2b) but the problem is that the bench time units on the table are the making of one product, so for example product 3 is made in bench 1 for an hour, bench 2 for an hour and bench 3 for an hour. So I am at loss at how should I even begin with this.

If anyone could give me any pointers or how to even start (Using matrices? Simplex table? Although not sure how to solve it with that).

Comment: If $x_{i}$ denotes the number of units of $T_{i}$, $i=1,2,3,4,5$ wouldn't the LPP be as follows? Maximize $f=2x_{1}+x_{2}+3x_{3}-x_{4}+2x_{5}$ subject to the constraints $x_{1}+2x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{5}\leq 100$, $x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}\leq 80$, $x_{1}+x_{3}+x_{4}\leq 80$ and $x_{i}\geq 0$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: What about a possibility of multiple products in production - for example product 1 is in production in bench 1, then another could be made in bench 2/3?

Comment: By the way, there are a few free online Simplex Method tools that can assist you in checking the correctness of your solution. Try, for example, http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should define the variables:

$x_i$: The amount of units of product $T_i$, which are produced.

The first constraint is, that bench 1 can be used at most 100 hours.

$x_1+ 2x_2+x_3+0\cdot x_4+x_5\leq 100$

The constraints two and three are constructed similarly.

Then the objective function is

$\texttt{max} \ \ 2x_1+ 1x_2+3x_3-x_4+2x_5$

And finally the definition set of the variables: $x_1,x_2 \geq 0$.

This problem can be solved by applying the simplex-method. You should read a little bit about it and then ask specific questions.

Simplex table:

All the constraints have a $\leq$-sign. Thus you have to add a slack variable, $s_i$, for every constraint. The coefficient of the objective function have to be muliplied by (-1).

$$\begin{array}{|m{cm}|m{1cm}|}
\hline x_1   &  x_2 & x_3  & x_4 & x_5 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & RHS\\  \hline 
\hline  -2& -1&-3 & 1 &-2&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 1& 2&1&0 &1 & 1&0&0&100 \\ \hline & & &  &  & \\ \hline & & &  & & \\ \hline \end{array}$$

The constraints two and three have to be inserted in the table as well.

Comment: Thank you for answering! What about the problem of that one product can require multiple benches? (As like a production line)

Comment: @ReigoHein You could consider bench 1, bench2 and bench 3 as a production line. The products are all made by using all the benches. If the solution would be $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=20$, then the constraints for all three benches are satisfied. Now you can assume, that the products a made by using the benches in the order 1,2,3.